# Why this error appear for "before update trigger" between two table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, beforeupdate

I made a "emp" table and "audit" table then I want to update audit table from emps table .

[image]

[image]

and then error is continuosly appear, anyone able to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include your code as actual text, indented by four spaces, in your question, rather than as image links.  Off the top of my head, that `select` statement you have in the trigger looks suspicious.

Comment: Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

What is `select emps`?

Presumably you want something like this:

```
insert into audit ( . . . )
    select new.emp_name, new.dept_name, . . . ;
```

`new` is how you refer to the new values.

(Or if you want the old values, use `old`.)